# How to add background color to a section

Tags: html, css

Code:

```css
.headline {
  font: 150 50px/0.8 'Pacifico', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 7px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="main">
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Profile </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Notifications </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Messages </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Logout </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="headline">

  <p>
    The Social Network
  </p>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
```

[image]

Here I want to display the same color that is in navigation bar until the horizontal line below social network.
I have given the html code above.
Please suggest a way to do it.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: you can’t put tags between `<head>` and `<body>`. Have you used the CSS `background` property anywhere?

Comment: That is the PHP part. I am just asking how to apply background color here. I want to add background color upto the horizontal line below social network.

Comment: well what is the rendered html structure of that section ? you only show us the html of the headline and `main` . Plus, why is `main` containing the `nav` ? Nav should be in Header, other content inside Main and then Footer

Answer (score -3):

just add a background-color: ;
to you .headline style